# How to pass Rscript -e a multiline string?

Tags: r, stdin, rscript

Is there a way to provide the code to `Rscript -e` in multiple lines?

This is possible in vanilla R

```
R --vanilla <<code
a <- "hello\n"
cat(a)
code
```

But using `Rscript` I get two different things depending on the R version.

```
# R 3.0.2 gives two ignores
Rscript -e '
quote> a <- 3+3
quote> cat(a, "\n")
quote> '
# ARGUMENT 'cat(a,~+~"' __ignored__
# ARGUMENT '")' __ignored__

Rscript -e 'a <- 3+3;cat(a, "\n")'
# ARGUMENT '")' __ignored__

# R 2.15.3 gives an ignore for the multiline, but it works with semicolons
Rscript -e '
quote> a <- 3+3
quote> cat(a, "\n")
quote> '
# ARGUMENT 'cat(a,~+~"\n")' __ignored__

Rscript -e 'a <- 3+3;cat(a, "\n")'
6
```

I'm clearly using the wrong syntax. What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: If you're running Linux or OS X, you could use [**littler**](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/littler.html), which appears to allow line continuations. (See example on the linked webpage.)

Comment: Automatic +1 for mentioning the right tool :)

Comment: I guess this is a bug in `Rscript`? Or at least, a not-entirely-complete feature? I don't mean this as a criticism of Rscript, just an observation that newlines aren't handled as expected

Comment: If the `R --vanilla <<heredoc ...` syntax works, is there any reason to try and use `Rscript -e` for this?

Answer (score 14):

Update: I think the problem was spacing and quotes. This worked (on windows):

```
Rscript -e "a <- 3+3; cat(a,'\n')"
6
```

On Mac, you have to escape the escape character:

```
Rscript -e 'a <- 3+3; cat(a,"\\n")'
```

You can also put each expression separately.

```
Rscript -e "a <- 3+3" -e "cat(a)"
```

Comment: `Rscript -e "a <- 3+3; cat(a,'\n')"` doesn't work for me on a mac with R 3.0.2, but using the `-e` could be a decent workaround

Comment: I am using windows right now, because I am at work. But I have a Mac at home. I will check it there when I get home.

Comment: This works in MacOS: Rscript -e 'a <- 3+3; cat(a,"\\n")'

Comment: @Hansi you're right. I didn't know that R 3 chokes with `"\n"` but R 2 doesn't. I wonder why

Comment: to expand on @Hansi's comment: it's also worth noting that the outer quotes must be single and the inner quotes must be double or this method doesn't work.