# Execute multiline R expression from shell (with indentation)

Tags: r, bash, shell, r-markdown

I'm trying to achieve what you might naively write as:

```
R -e "
rmarkdown::render(
  'MyDocument.Rmd', 
  params = list(
    year = 2017
  ),
  output_file = 'ExampleRnotebook.html'
)
"
```

So that I can make nicely formatted submission scripts to run on a cluster.

I've tried some variants on the below, I'm wondering if there might be an alternative approach to do this with the `R -f` flag?

```
read -r -d '' EXP << EOF
rmarkdown::render(
  'MyDocument.Rmd',
  params = list(
    year = 2017
  ),
  output_file = 'ExampleRnotebook.html'
)
EOF
R -e "$EXP"
```

but I get a series of errors that look like this:

`ARGUMENT 'params~+~=~+~list(' __ignored__`

for the different lines of the expression, followed by:

```
> rmarkdown::render(
+ 
+ Error: unexpected end of input
```

---

To reproduce:

MyDocument.Rmd =

````
---
title: "R Notebook"
output: html_notebook
params: 
  year: 0000
---

```{r}
params$year

```
````

---

This works fine:

```
read -r -d '' EXP <<- EOF 
rmarkdown::render('MyDocument.Rmd', params = list(year = 2017 ), output_file = 'ExampleRnotebook.html')
EOF
R -e "$EXP"
```

but gets hard to read with longer param lists

Comment: try `<< -EOF` (with a dash) to keep the indentation

Comment: I did try that: `read -r -d'' EXP <<- EOS` and I get this error: `ERROR: option '-e' requires a non-empty argument`

Comment: Try `echo "$EXP"` before calling `R`. If the result shown looks like what you expect, then maybe additional flags are required for `R` to read multiline input

Comment: Save the script as file then call `Rscript myScript.R`, [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18306362/run-r-script-from-command-line)?

Comment: hmm the echo is what I expect but i'm still getting the `ARGUMENT '~+~~+~'MyDocument.Rmd',' __ignored__` errors I think it must be something to do with the way R parses the contents of `-e''`

Comment: Thanks but i'm trying to avoid the `Rscript myScript.R` approach @zx8754 as then I end up with 2 throw-away scripts to write when I submit a job to the cluster.

Comment: Use `--vanilla` flag? [see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21733137)

Comment: nope same result with `R --vanilla` / `Rscript --vanilla` as in that post which might be useful though...

Comment: using multiple `-e` flags as in that post only appears to work if each is a complete expression that could be terminated with an `;` or newline

Comment: Do you mean `R --vanilla` doesn't work with codes with indentation?

Comment: yes adding `--vanilla` works fine in the one line versions and it does not change the errors in when the command is split across lines. which is consistent with what I understand `--vanilla` mode is supposed to do, I don't see any reason why it would alter the parsing behaviour of arguments to `-e`

Comment: I tested with `R --no-save <<code` and `R --vanilla  <<code` multi line formatted code, it works. Maybe add R version?

Comment: interesting could you share your exact syntax? - i'm using R 3.4.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me (R version 3.5.0):

```
R --no-save <<code
for(i in 1:3) {
  i + 
    2
}
print(i)

runif(5,
      1,10)
code
```

**Note:** line-breaks and paddings are intentional.

Comment: Note this approach bypasses the use of the `-e` flag entirely and makes use of the same behaviour as `echo 'print("Hello World")' | R --no-save`. (Thanks @zx8754)